# node.JS application in docker container

Tags: node.js, exception, docker, apache-kafka

I have my node.JS application running in a docker container. While most of the functioning of this setup is normal but it fails to work with kafka-node module. Exception thrown is

```
/app/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/snappy/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
        ^
Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:434:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at bindings (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/snappy/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/snappy/snappy.js:2:34)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

My Dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM node:4

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm cache clean
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8085
CMD []

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "runscript.sh"]
```

And for further information, Kafka is running on separate server. All relevant ports are opened and I can telnet successfully for checking them.

Comment: It seems to be related to snappy: https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/355 The dependency will become optional for kafka-node, I don't know if you can wait.

Comment: Ya you are right. I had to revert to older versions of node.JS for doing away with this issue. Thanks.